# How to Prevent JAX-WS Web Method Extra Tag

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jax-ws

I am trying to use JAX-WS web methods in java. And I encounter with some design issue. I trying to change xml structure which generated from web service method. Some code parts are written below. I hope i can ask what i want.

I create a test java class like below.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"testKod"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "testService")
public class TestService {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String testKod;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String uyeKod;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String islemRefNo;
...
}
```

And I implement the web service and method.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "testService")
@WebResult(name="testServiceResponse")
public TestServiceResponse testService(@WebParam(name = "params") TestService params){

    TestServiceResponse response = new TestServiceResponse();
    try {
        response.setUyeKod(params.getUyeKod());
        response.setIslemRefNo(params.getIslemRefNo());
        response.setTestKod(params.getTestKod());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.getHata().setAciklama(Convert.fromDBtoTR(TExceptionUtil.getExceptionMessage(e)));
        response.getHata().setHataKodu("100");

    }
    return response;
}
```

After I test with SAOP-UI and export xsd, the client request looks below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.ddd.ccc.bbb.aaa.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:testService>
        <params  islemRefNo="1212" uyeKod="XXX" >
            <testKod>1212</testKod>
        </params>
      </ws:testService>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But i dont want to see params tag, I want to see like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.ddd.ccc.bbb.aaa.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:testService islemRefNo="1212" uyeKod="XXX" >
            <testKod>1212</testKod>
      </ws:testService>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Briefly my xsd like below;

```
<xs:complexType name="testService">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="params" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="testKod" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="uyeKod" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="islemRefNo" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

But i want to looks like that. Also i faced with same issue in response xml.

```
 <xs:element name="testService">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="testKod" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="uyeKod" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="islemRefNo" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which kind of style binding you are using (RPC or Document). You can specify it with the following annotation:

```
@SOAPBinding(
    style=Style.RPC,
    use=Use.LITERAL,
    parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.BARE
)
```

I think the best configuration for you is RPC/Literal.

Look at this guide https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/ to see the difference among all the methods